# run-time error 1004 Could not run the paste method of worksheet class

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have a problem in a macro I made. it was working perfectly, until he started giving this error. and then when I go into debug. shows the error in the following field:
I will post all the code here.

```
Sub Terca()
'
' Terca Macro
'
' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+q
'
Range("I55").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-33
Range("E17").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E18").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("F17").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-6]C[-2]:R[10]C[-2],Dados!R[-12]C[-2])"
Range("E17").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste   !!!! <-- ERROR ---> !!!!
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-7]C[-1],Dados!R[-12]C[-1])"
Range("F18").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-7]C[-1]:R[9]C[-1],Dados!R[-13]C[-1])"
Range("E18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-8]C,Dados!R[-13]C)"
Range("F17").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-7]C[-2]:R[10]C[-2],Dados!R[-12]C[-2])"
Range("F18").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-8]C[-1]:R[9]C[-1],Dados!R[-13]C[-1])"
Range("E21").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E22").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("F21").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-10]C[4]:R[6]C[4],Dados!R[-16]C[4])"
Range("E21").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-11]C[5],Dados!R[-16]C[5])"
Range("F22").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-11]C[1]:R[5]C[1],Dados!R[-17]C[1])"
Range("E22").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-12]C[2],Dados!R[-17]C[2])"
Range("F21").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-11]C[4]:R[6]C[4],Dados!R[-16]C[4])"
Range("F22").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-12]C[1]:R[5]C[1],Dados!R[-17]C[1])"
Range("F23").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Range("E25:E26").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("F25").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-14]C[7]:R[2]C[7],Dados!R[-20]C[7])"
Range("E25").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-15]C[8],Dados!R[-20]C[8])"
Range("F26").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-15]C[8]:R[1]C[8],Dados!R[-21]C[8])"
Range("E26").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-16]C[9],Dados!R[-21]C[9])"
Range("F25").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-15]C[7]:R[2]C[7],Dados!R[-20]C[7])"
Range("F26").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-16]C[8]:R[1]C[8],Dados!R[-21]C[8])"
Range("F31").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-20]C[11]:R[-4]C[11],Dados!R[-26]C[11])"
Range("E31").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-21]C[12],Dados!R[-26]C[12])"
Range("F32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-21]C[12]:R[-5]C[12],Dados!R[-27]C[12])"
Range("E32").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-22]C[13],Dados!R[-27]C[13])"
Range("F32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-22]C[12]:R[-5]C[12],Dados!R[-27]C[12])"
Range("F31").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-21]C[11]:R[-4]C[11],Dados!R[-26]C[11])"
Range("F32").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Range("F35").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-24]C[13]:R[-8]C[13],Dados!R[-30]C[13])"
Range("E35").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-25]C[14],Dados!R[-30]C[14])"
Range("F36").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-25]C[14]:R[-9]C[14],Dados!R[-31]C[14])"
Range("E36").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-26]C[15],Dados!R[-31]C[15])"
Range("F35").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-25]C[13]:R[-8]C[13],Dados!R[-30]C[13])"
Range("F36").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-26]C[14]:R[-9]C[14],Dados!R[-31]C[14])"
Range("F37").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("E42:E43").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("F42").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-31]C[17]:R[-15]C[17],Dados!R[-37]C[17])"
Range("E42").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[18],Dados!R[-37]C[18])"
Range("F43").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[18]:R[-16]C[18],Dados!R[-38]C[18])"
Range("E43").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-33]C[19],Dados!R[-38]C[19])"
Range("F43").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-33]C[18]:R[-16]C[18],Dados!R[-38]C[18])"
Range("F42").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[17]:R[-15]C[17],Dados!R[-37]C[17])"
Range("E46:E47").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("F46").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-35]C[21]:R[-19]C[21],Dados!R[-41]C[21])"
Range("E46").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[22],Dados!R[-41]C[22])"
Range("F47").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[22]:R[-20]C[22],Dados!R[-42]C[22])"
Range("E47").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-37]C[23],Dados!R[-42]C[23])"
Range("F46").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[21]:R[-19]C[21],Dados!R[-41]C[21])"
Range("F47").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-37]C[22]:R[-20]C[22],Dados!R[-42]C[22])"
Range("L42").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-31]C[13]:R[-15]C[13],Dados!R[-37]C[13])"
Range("K42").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[14],Dados!R[-37]C[14])"
Range("L43").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[14]:R[-16]C[14],Dados!R[-38]C[14])"
Range("K43").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-33]C[15],Dados!R[-38]C[15])"
Range("L46").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-35]C[17]:R[-19]C[17],Dados!R[-41]C[17])"
Range("K46").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-35]C[17]:R[-19]C[17],Dados!R[-41]C[17])"
Range("K46").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[18],Dados!R[-41]C[18])"
Range("L47").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[18]:R[-20]C[18],Dados!R[-42]C[18])"
Range("K47").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-37]C[19],Dados!R[-42]C[19])"
Range("L47").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-37]C[18]:R[-20]C[18],Dados!R[-42]C[18])"
Range("L46").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[17]:R[-19]C[17],Dados!R[-41]C[17])"
Range("L43").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-33]C[14]:R[-16]C[14],Dados!R[-38]C[14])"
Range("L42").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[13]:R[-15]C[13],Dados!R[-37]C[13])"
Range("P48").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't copied anything to paste.

Comment: Avoid selecting cells and using ActiveCell if you want to improve performance; see the following [Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1490783).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may I suggest the below improvements to your (recorded?) code:

```
Sub Terca()
'
' Terca Macro
'
' Atalho do teclado: Ctrl+q
'
Range("E17:E18,E21:E22,E25:E26,E46:E47,E42:E43").ClearContents
Range("F17").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-6]C[-2]:R[10]C[-2],Dados!R[-12]C[-2])"
Range("E17").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-7]C[-1],Dados!R[-12]C[-1])"
Range("F18").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-7]C[-1]:R[9]C[-1],Dados!R[-13]C[-1])"
Range("E18").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-8]C,Dados!R[-13]C)"
Range("F17").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-7]C[-2]:R[10]C[-2],Dados!R[-12]C[-2])"
Range("F18").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-8]C[-1]:R[9]C[-1],Dados!R[-13]C[-1])"
Range("E21").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-10]C[4]:R[6]C[4],Dados!R[-16]C[4])"
Range("E21").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-11]C[5],Dados!R[-16]C[5])"
Range("F22").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-11]C[1]:R[5]C[1],Dados!R[-17]C[1])"
Range("E22").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-12]C[2],Dados!R[-17]C[2])"
Range("F21").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-11]C[4]:R[6]C[4],Dados!R[-16]C[4])"
Range("F22").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-12]C[1]:R[5]C[1],Dados!R[-17]C[1])"
Range("F25").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-14]C[7]:R[2]C[7],Dados!R[-20]C[7])"
Range("E25").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-15]C[8],Dados!R[-20]C[8])"
Range("F26").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-15]C[8]:R[1]C[8],Dados!R[-21]C[8])"
Range("E26").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-16]C[9],Dados!R[-21]C[9])"
Range("F25").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-15]C[7]:R[2]C[7],Dados!R[-20]C[7])"
Range("F26").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Dados!R[-16]C[8]:R[1]C[8],Dados!R[-21]C[8])"
Range("F31").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-20]C[11]:R[-4]C[11],Dados!R[-26]C[11])"
Range("E31").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-21]C[12],Dados!R[-26]C[12])"
Range("F32").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-21]C[12]:R[-5]C[12],Dados!R[-27]C[12])"
Range("E32").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-22]C[13],Dados!R[-27]C[13])"
Range("F32").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-22]C[12]:R[-5]C[12],Dados!R[-27]C[12])"
Range("F31").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-21]C[11]:R[-4]C[11],Dados!R[-26]C[11])"
Range("F35").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-24]C[13]:R[-8]C[13],Dados!R[-30]C[13])"
Range("E35").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-25]C[14],Dados!R[-30]C[14])"
Range("F36").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-25]C[14]:R[-9]C[14],Dados!R[-31]C[14])"
Range("E36").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-26]C[15],Dados!R[-31]C[15])"
Range("F35").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-25]C[13]:R[-8]C[13],Dados!R[-30]C[13])"
Range("F36").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-26]C[14]:R[-9]C[14],Dados!R[-31]C[14])"
Range("F42").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-31]C[17]:R[-15]C[17],Dados!R[-37]C[17])"
Range("E42").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[18],Dados!R[-37]C[18])"
Range("F43").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[18]:R[-16]C[18],Dados!R[-38]C[18])"
Range("E43").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-33]C[19],Dados!R[-38]C[19])"
Range("F43").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-33]C[18]:R[-16]C[18],Dados!R[-38]C[18])"
Range("F42").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[17]:R[-15]C[17],Dados!R[-37]C[17])"
Range("F46").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-35]C[21]:R[-19]C[21],Dados!R[-41]C[21])"
Range("E46").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[22],Dados!R[-41]C[22])"
Range("F47").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[22]:R[-20]C[22],Dados!R[-42]C[22])"
Range("E47").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-37]C[23],Dados!R[-42]C[23])"
Range("F46").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[21]:R[-19]C[21],Dados!R[-41]C[21])"
Range("F47").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-37]C[22]:R[-20]C[22],Dados!R[-42]C[22])"
Range("L42").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-31]C[13]:R[-15]C[13],Dados!R[-37]C[13])"
Range("K42").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[14],Dados!R[-37]C[14])"
Range("L43").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[14]:R[-16]C[14],Dados!R[-38]C[14])"
Range("K43").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-33]C[15],Dados!R[-38]C[15])"
Range("L46").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-35]C[17]:R[-19]C[17],Dados!R[-41]C[17])"
Range("K46").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-35]C[17]:R[-19]C[17],Dados!R[-41]C[17])"
Range("K46").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[18],Dados!R[-41]C[18])"
Range("L47").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[18]:R[-20]C[18],Dados!R[-42]C[18])"
Range("K47").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-37]C[19],Dados!R[-42]C[19])"
Range("L47").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-37]C[18]:R[-20]C[18],Dados!R[-42]C[18])"
Range("L46").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-36]C[17]:R[-19]C[17],Dados!R[-41]C[17])"
Range("L43").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-33]C[14]:R[-16]C[14],Dados!R[-38]C[14])"
Range("L42").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Dados!R[-32]C[13]:R[-15]C[13],Dados!R[-37]C[13])"

End Sub
```

no need to select cells before assigning a value.
don't try to paste if there is nothing in the clipboard suitable for pasting

HTH

Philip

Comment: thx, it's right!
I use the macro recorder, and manual edit :P

Comment: also, before adding all those formulas, may be worth setting `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of the procedure, then calling `Application.Calculate` at the end and resetting it to Automatioc